# how to remove an element from an array contained in a formData ()

Tags: javascript

I have a code with which I intend to attach an array of files on the "anexos_detalle_reunion" key.
In my code, I have executed this line of code 3 times, so it is normal to add an element named "anexos_detalle_reunion[]" to my formData () 3 times. I need to specifically delete the "anexos_detalle_reunion[]" key located in position 1 and keep the others.

[image]

how can I do it?

```
var FormData=new FormData();
formData.append('anexos_detalle_reunion[]', file, file.name);


fileChange(event:any) {
   let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
   console.log(fileList);
   if(fileList.length > 0) {
       let file: File = fileList[0];
       console.log(file,file.name);
       this.formData.append('anexos_detalle_reunion[]', file, file.name);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't append it the first time? In supporting browsers, you could [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete) the key and reappend only the values you want, but I don't see why you couldn't do it from the beginning.

Comment: @Kaiido In other words, I need to create an array of files. and I need to know how to delete one of those files in the array that I will send.

Comment: And we need to know how you do create this Array of Files, and what prevents you from creating it the correct way from the beginning.

Comment: @Kaiido mmm I think I understand you. change the question, how can I attach n files and then send them, and before doing so, delete some?

Comment: We still need to know how you do generate the FormData. Are you doing like `new FormData(myFormElement)`? or are you rally calling `formData.append(...`

Comment: @Kaiido FormData=new FormData();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187162/discussion-between-kaiido-and-yavg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't build your FormData until you have to upload it to your server. 
A FormData object is not practical to store data. There are many other Objects in js that can do it way better, for instance a simple Array is all you need in your case.

So in the input's change event, you push the new Files in an Array.
You do the modifications you want from this Array.
When it's time to send it to the server, you build your FormData with what remains in the Array:

```js
const files = []; // a simple Array;

inp.onchange = e => {
  const file = inp.files[0];
  files.push(file); // store in the Array
  makeRemoveButton(file);
}

btn.onclick = e => { // could be form.onsubmit
  // here we build the FormData
  const fd = new FormData();
  files.forEach(f => {
    fd.append('files[]', f, f.name);
  });
  console.log(...fd);
  // fetch(..., {body: fd, ...
};


function makeRemoveButton(file) {
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.textContent = 'remove ' + file.name;
  btn.onclick = e => {
    btn.remove();
    files.splice(files.indexOf(file), 1);
  };
  document.body.append(btn);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
<button id="btn">send</button><br>
```